# Acronyms | Reference| abbreviation | Overleaf | Latex

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, overleaf, acronyms

I add Acronyms and Reference in Overleaf.

```
\usepackage[acronym,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.8\hsize}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\printglossary[type=acronym,style=long]

\arcfull{ny} is a city \citet{author2000}.
```

The reference list showed me incorrectly

```
Author(2000). ny city.
```

It should show me like this, which is original title.

```
Author(2000). NY city.
```

I would like to keep NY in main body, and reference does not change with the Acronyms, reference list keep original title.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: Do you produce the NY in the references also with `glossaries`? It would really help if you could turn the code snippet so far into a fully compilable example document that we can run as-is. That way we can all be sure we are talking about the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone! I manually add {} in bibtext of reference to keep it uppercase. It seems like it's not because of Acronyms.

Comment: This is why a minimal working example would have been helpful.  You were completely focused on the acronyms, and didn't really give us much information to go on.